# Designer and inherited ContextMenuStrip

Tags: winforms, designer, contextmenustrip

I have a problem, what designer doesn't add inherited `ContextMenuStrip` to the `components`. Here is how to reproduce the problem:

1. Create new project (windows forms application).
2. Add to the form `ContextMenuStrip` via designer, it will generate this:

   ```
   private void InitializeComponent()
   {
       this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
       this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Create `MyContextMenuStrip` class:

   ```
   public class MyContextMenuStrip : ContextMenuStrip
   {
   }
   ```
4. Compile and add to the form `MyContextMenuStrip` via designer, it will generate this:

   ```
   private void InitializeComponent()
   {
       this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
       this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
       this.myContextMenuStrip1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.MyContextMenuStrip();
       ...
   }
   ```

WTF? Why it's not adding `MyContextMenuStrip` to the components???

And I need menu to be present in `components` for my localization manager (to automatically translate menus). Do I forgot some attribute, interface or override??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio isn't initializing your `MyContextMenuStrip` with a `Container` because your control doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `Container` as a parameter.

Create a constructor in your `MyContextMenuStrip` that takes a `System.ComponentModel.IContainer` and then pass this parameter to your control's base class using the `base` keyword:

```
class MyContextMenuStrip : ContextMenuStrip
{
    public MyContextMenuStrip(System.ComponentModel.IContainer c) : base(c) { }
}
```

After doing this you'll find that when you add your `MyContextMenuStrip` to a Form using the designer, VS will generate the code you want in your Form's `InitializeComponent` method:

```
this.myContextMenuStrip1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.MyContextMenuStrip(this.components);
```

Comment: Thanks, was already going another way (enumerating controls and checking their `Control.ContextMenuStrip`), but it doesn't works well (if `MyContextMenuStrip` is not assigned to either of control and suppose to be shown programmatically - then I can't find it).. and then you have come here =D

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you, I learned something and your question is very well laid out.